# Importing Overpass API response to PostGIS with ogr2ogr creates empty table

Tags: postgis, gdal, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, overpass-api

I need to import parking polygons from OSM to PostGIS. But when I import data from Overpass API using ogr2ogr it keeps creating an empty table (with the expected columns as to per osmconf.ini). Import from an extract file (*.osm.pbf) is working fine. Why is the import of the Overpass response not working, and is there a better way to import specific OSM elements? The process is to be automated later.

Overpass API request (response saved to parkings.osm):

```
https://overpass.osm.ch/api/interpreter?data=[bbox];way[amenity=parking];out geom;&bbox=7.56204,46.72907,7.65333,46.78813
```

ogr2ogr command:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=localhost port=5432 user=osm_import password=pwd dbname=somedb active_schema=osm" "parkings.osm" multipolygons -nln osm_parking_polygons -overwrite -skipfailures
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using out geom; in your Overpass QL query, you're requesting a response in a format which is not 100% compatible with OSM XML 0.6 format. However, ogr2ogr doesn't understand these Overpass API specific format extensions.

For an OSM XML compatible response, you need to change your query to

```
(way[amenity=parking];>;);out meta;
```

instead of

```
way[amenity=parking];out geom;
```

You can also open your query in overpass turbo, and then hit Export -> "load data into an OSM editor: JOSM". This way, the overpass turbo will try to "repair" your query, and make it OSM XML compliant.

Comment: your query works perfectly, thanks!